# Android Toast did not show after open Gallery and pick image

Tags: android, android-toast

I want to show Toast (or progress bar) when clicking on the button "btnSearchImg". If before upload image, button clicked say "first pick image from gallary" and if after upload image clicked say "waiting". the toast before uploading image work fine but after uploading didn't work fine! my entire Activity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_by_image);
    Toasty.Config.getInstance().setTextSize(15).apply();

    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    mEditor.putString(PREF_SKIP,null);
    if(mSharedPreferences.contains(PREF_SKIP)){
        Log.i("payment", "true");
    } else {
        try {

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERORR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    context = getApplicationContext();
    pbImgRetrvialProccess = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pbImgRetrvialProccess);
    tvPermissionLoadImg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPermissionLoadImg);
    tvPermissionLoadImg.setTypeface(Base.getIranSansFont());
    TextView tvSearchImageToolBarText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSearchImageToolBarText);
    tvSearchImageToolBarText.setTypeface(Base.getIranSansFont());
    ivGalleryImgLoad = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivGalleryImgLoad);
    btnSearchImgLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearchImgLoad);
    btnSearchImg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearchImg);
    btnSearchImgLoad.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSearchImg.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public StringBuilder uniformQuantization( File filePath ){...}

private StringBuilder chHistogram( Mat newImage ){...}

private void CopyAssets(String filename){...}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {...}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSearchImgLoad:
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PICK_IMAGE);}
            OpenGallery();
            break;

        case R.id.btnSearchImg:
            Toasty.success(getBaseContext(), "Waiting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            FindSimilarRequestedImage();              
            break;
    }
}

private void OpenGallery() {
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}


private void FindSimilarRequestedImage() {

    if (ivGalleryImgLoad.getDrawable() != null) {
        File loadedImageFilePath = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri));
        queryFeatureX = uniformQuantization(loadedImageFilePath);
        dateiLesenStringBuilder();
    } else {
        Toasty.error(getBaseContext(), "first pick image from gallary", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data != null) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PICK_IMAGE);

        } else {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            ivGalleryImgLoad.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            tvPermissionLoadImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}

private void dateiLesenStringBuilder() {
    FEATURE_PATH = context.getCacheDir().getPath() + "/" + FEATURE_NAME;
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(FEATURE_PATH);
        InputStream in = context.getAssets().open("coins/"+FEATURE_NAME);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
            out.write(buffer, 0, ch);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    final File featureList = new File(FEATURE_PATH);
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String sCurrentLine;
                int lines = 0;
                BufferedReader newbw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(featureList.getAbsolutePath()));
                while (newbw.readLine() != null)
                    lines++;
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(featureList.getAbsolutePath()));
                ArrayList<Double> nDistVal = new ArrayList<Double>();
                ArrayList<String> nImagePath = new ArrayList<String>();
                int count = 0;
                while ((sCurrentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] featX = sCurrentLine.split(";")[1].split(" ");
                    nImagePath.add(sCurrentLine.split(";")[0]);
                    nDistVal.add(Distance.distL2(featX, queryFeatureX.toString().split(" ")));
                    count++;
                }
                ArrayList<Double> nstore = new ArrayList<Double>(nDistVal); // may need to be new ArrayList(nfit)
                double maxDistVal = Collections.max(nDistVal);
                Collections.sort(nDistVal);
                sortedNImagePath = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int n = 0; n < nDistVal.size(); n++) {
                    int index = nstore.indexOf(nDistVal.get(n));
                    sortedNImagePath.add(nImagePath.get(index));
                    sortedNImageDistanceValues.add(String.valueOf(nDistVal.get(n) / maxDistVal));
                    String filePath = sortedNImagePath.get(0);
                    String minDistanceImg = sortedNImageDistanceValues.get(n);
                    FileNameFromPath = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    System.out.println("Distance values -> " + FileNameFromPath.toString());
                    System.out.println("Distance values -> " + minDistanceImg.toString());
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                String x = ex.getMessage();
                System.out.println("ERORR" + x);
            }
            if (in != null) try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent imgSearchedCoinNameIntent = new Intent(SearchByImageActivity.this, ImageSearchedCoinActivity.class);
                imgSearchedCoinNameIntent.putExtra("imgSearchedCoinName", FileNameFromPath);
                startActivity(imgSearchedCoinNameIntent);
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(runner, "Code Executer");
    t.start();
  }
}
```

If I put the "Waiting..." Toast after the `FindSimilarRequestedImage()` the toast will show up, but I need the toast show immediately after clicking on the `btnSearchImg`.

NOTE: Also in the `dateiLesenStringBuilder()` I removed the thread t that this part of code runs in normal flow and serial, but nothing changes!

Comment: You mean first the function FindSimilarRequestedImage() will run completely and its toast "first pick ..." will be shown, then toast "waiting..." will be seen?!

Comment: actually I should put the "Waiting..." Toast in "if" that check image uploaded or not, and if uploaded, then show the toast, I did this too but nothing change! Also, I comment the function FindSimilarRequestedImage() and toast appear successfully!!!

Comment: Put toast in the function before  if (ivGalleryImgLoad.getDrawable() != null)

Comment: Actually I should put toast in the if (ivGalleryImgLoad.getDrawable() != null) to check image uploaded or not, I do this too, but nothing changes! Something Wierd that I comment FindSimilarRequestedImage() and the toast appear successfully!!

Comment: Don't invoke the function, I mean after toast "warning" write your function

Comment: It didn't work! :(

Comment: Instead of toast use logcat to see if they run sequentially or not

Comment: Maybe toast takes time to run

Comment: Yes, I think this the problem! and solved with delay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by putting the part of code in delay like below:

```
private void FindSimilarRequestedImage() {
    if (ivGalleryImgLoad.getDrawable() != null) {
        pbImgRetrvialProccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toasty.success(getBaseContext(), "Waiting ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                File loadedImageFilePath = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri));
                queryFeatureX = uniformQuantization(loadedImageFilePath);
                dateiLesenStringBuilder();
            }

        }, 5000);
    } else {
        Toasty.error(getBaseContext(), "first pick image from gallary", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Now before destroying activity throw functions, I first show the toast, then run other functions!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of toast use logcat to see if they run sequentially or not, maybe toast takes time to run